# Fazer top 10 verificando 3 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

Tenho 3 tabelas:

**patrocinadores**

```
id | id_patrocinador | id_usuario
```

**cotas**

```
id | id_user | quantidade
```

**usuarios**

```
id | nome | login
```

O que preciso fazer é um TOP 10 aonde liste 10 usuários que tem mais **patrocinados** com cotas ativas. Por exemplo:

```
1 - João - 10 indicados ativos
2 - Maria - 9 indicados aitvos
...
```

Tentei fazer o **SELECT** de várias formas mas não consegui chegar a nenhum resultado certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO**

Montei um SQL:

```
SELECT u.nome, u.login, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) FROM patrocinadores AS p INNER JOIN cotas AS c ON c.id_user = p.id_usuario WHERE c.status = 1 AND p.id_patrocinador = u.id) AS quantidade FROM usuarios AS u ORDER BY quantidade DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Estou sem SQL na minha máquina agora
Tente isto:

select
usuarios.id
,usuarios.nome
,count(patrocinadores.id)
from usuarios inner join patrocinadores on usuarios.id = patrocinadores.id_usuario
group by usuarios.id, usuarios.nome
order by 3 desc

Comment: Não deu, retornou o count(patrocinadores.id) tudo como 1... Precisa verificar quais do patrocinadores.id_usuario está ativo nas cotas, ou seja cotas.status = 1